# Use Google OAuth2 iOS client with universal links

Tags: ios, google-oauth

I'm creating an iOS application with support for Google OAuth2. After enabling OAuth2 in the developer console, I create credentials for an iOS client, but the redirect url (a custom URL scheme) is hardcoded and I cannot change it.

This goes against Apple's recommendation to use Universal Links.
This then requires me to either ignore Apple recommendations and use a custom URL scheme, or force me to create a Web server based client, which supports custom redirect URLs but also requires a client secret, and embed that client secret in the app, which is also insecure.

Google's own documentation is not clear and states that `client_secret` [should not be considered secret](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#installed), but also [shouldn't be published](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/best-practices#handle-client-credentials-securely)

Is there a way to use `https://` based redirect for iOS clients ? If not, what's the lesser of the two evils in terms of security ?